# Choosing one measurement in a chart in QlikSense

Tags: charts, qliksense

I have created a chart where the x-axis (dimensions) is months, and for the y-axis (expressions) I have a few different data bars, which are compared to the first bar (which is the total).

It is possible to add a slicer or something like that so that I can choose which measurements I want to see? For example, sometimes I need to hide some of them.

In the example bellow: main bar is dark blue one and the other bars for each month is a comparison vs the first one. How can I select for example, to see only the green bars vs the main blue bar and not see all the other bars in that month?

[image]

Comment: using the latest version of Qlik Sense (2.2.4), you can now use alternative expressions that allows the user to pick which expressions to show in a chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use filter pane, add filter for each bar, you can select which bar you want to see by these filter.

Comment: Thank you,but is it possible to do it without filter?

Comment: i Think its not possible when u are not using any filter, if u only want to show spesific bar (not all bar) you can use set analysis :)